# How to cmp multiple files with relative paths using bash

Tags: bash, cmp

I have a directory called filesystem that looks a little like this:

```
- filesystem
  - etc
    - systemd
      - system
        - custom.service
        - custom2.service
  - hostname
```

These files are copied into the root directory then need to be verified. For example: `filesystem/etc/hostname` is copied into `/etc/hostname`.

I've tried this to write a bash script to compare every file in filesystem.

```
for file in $(find filesystem -type f)
do
  cmp file ${file#filesystem}
done
```

The purpose of `${file#filesystem}` is to remove the 'filesystem' from the path of the second file.

This isn't working - it returns 'No such file or directory'. How to fix this code?

Comment: Do you need `cmp $file ${file#filesystem}`, though the whole thing is going to break if you have any spaces or other such characters in any filenames, looping over the output of `find` is an antipattern and leads to difficulties

Comment: You're missing the `$` before `$file`. Is that the real code or a copying error?

Comment: to debug, change `cmd` to `echo`? Good luck.

Comment: @Barmar That was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @EricRenouf OK - could you suggest a better way in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the specific problem with your code is that you were missing a `$` to expand `file`.  That said, processing the output of `ls` or `find` can run into problems whenever filenames contain any `IFS` character.  Spaces are a common example, but newlines will trip up many attempts to handle the spaces.

One option for addressing this is to use `-exec` with `find` and invoking a shell, since you need some of the shell capabilities for parameter expansion.

Here we'll use `sh -c` with a string to run which is the `cmp` command, and we'll pass that `sh` 2 arguments the first being a placeholder that's the shell's name, the second being the filename parameter:

```
find filesystem -type f -exec sh -c 'cmp "$1" "${1#filesystem}"' _ {} \;
```

We quote the variables within `sh -c` and `find` will ensure `{}` is passed in correctly as a single argument.